# How are keywords developed?

Tags: java, compilation, keyword

Has Dr James Gosling written code for the Java keywords?

If **yes**,

- How can I view Java keywords code like we view source code?
- Is there any way to create a user defined keyword?

**Here's what I would guess:**  There is no Java keyword code, the Java compiler holds a list of keywords, which helps the compiler to understand code.

Is this guess correct?

Comment: There is an interesting article about the flow control in java byte code - http://www.artima.com/underthehood/flowP.html - could be interesting, I think.

Comment: The Java compiler knows java keywords and what they mean. Only then it can transform java source code to Byte code (which again has *keywords*)

Comment: @aioobe: I voted to close this question because it is too broad as the issue is not narrowed down to be answered in concise ways: "How are keywords developed" is not specific enough for the [se] format __at all__. Just because the OP has accepted an answer doesn't mean anything at all, especially when you consider panic accept behavior from seeing as the question got closed. See the help center page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Has Dr James Gosling written code for Java keywords?

Yes, when he wrote the first Java compiler he probably wrote code to handle compilation of keywords.

> How to view Java keywords code like we view source code?

There is no "Java method" behind `while` or `if` etc. These are language primitives handled specially by the compiler.

> Is there any way to create user defined keyword?

No, you can't create user defined keywords. The semantics of the keywords are specified in the Java Language Specification and treated specially by the compiler.

> There is no Java keyword code. Java complier holds list of keywords, which helps the complier to understand code.

Yes. That's pretty much it.

<sup><sup>Source: I'm a javac developer</sup></sup>

Comment: "No, you can't create user defined keywords." While this statement is backed by the JLS, how do you feel about how libraries can exist to __override javac compilation behaviour__ based on how the compiler implementation can be experimentally modified (via reflection) by creating an annotation processor? For example: https://github.com/light/JOps

Comment: I'd say that doesn't seem very portable or stable. Any programmer in their right mind would probably agree that it would be bad practice to rely on such annotation processor.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a javac developer?

Comment: `javac` is the Java compiler developed by Oracle (and others) shipped with OpenJDK. I was an employee at Oracle and a member of the langtools team at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the process of writing a software able to turning a language in something else is done by "compiler of compilers" tools by specifying a grammar, typically a [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) form is used. The first usable version of the language are in many case used to create the compiler itself, in order to prove the language effectiveness. If you want to extend java by changing the keywords and adding different ones, you should create a new language, maybe starting from the [Java Grammar itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html).

Comment: Trivia: javac has a hand-written parser for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define your own keywords, you can take a look into Scala, in fact all the keywords in Scala are actually methods.

Here is an example where you can implement a method that works like a 'using' keyword in other languages, to dispose objects explicitly, http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/2007/08/25/implementing-the-disposable-pattern-in-scala/